# Зачем нужны template template параметры?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Приведите, пожалуйста, реальные примеры использования этих параметров, когда без них не обойтись либо они значительно упрощают код.

Comment: Вы про передачу шаблона в качестве аргумента другому шаблону?

Comment: @EOF `template<template<typename T> typename G>`

Comment: Как мы знаем, без любой конструкции, которой нет в Брейнфаке, вполне можно обойтись.

Comment: @bipll *либо они значительно упрощают код*

Answer (score 11):

Давайте посмотрим на код ниже:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <template <typename T> typename Cont>
class Foo
{
private:
    Cont<int> values;
};

template <typename Cont>
class Bar
{
private:
    Cont values;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<vector> fooVec;
    Bar<vector<int>> barVec;
    
    Foo<list> fooList;
    Bar<list<int>> barList;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Как видно, мы можем передать любой контейнер в оба класса. Так в чём разница? Разница в том, что в класс `Bar` у нас есть возможность передать контейнер другого типа. Нам никто не запрещает написать

```
Bar<list<double>> barList;
```

В свою очередь класс `Foo` дает возможность пользователю класса выбирать необходимый контейнер для хранения значений, но не дает возможность выбирать тип для этих значений.

---

Вот ещё один вариант использования. Например Вам необходимо хранить в обьекте класса два контейнера. И Вам важно, чтобы это были одинаковые контейнеры.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename Type1, typename Type2, template<typename T> typename Cont>
class Foo
{
private:
    Cont<Type1> first;
    Cont<Type2> second;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int, double, std::vector> obj1;
    Foo<char, bool, std::list> obj2;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Передавая шаблон в качестве параметра, Вы сможете гарантировать, что `first` и `second` будут одинаковыми контейнерами.

---

Эта возможность языка чаще используется в метапрограммировании. Попробуйте поискать на гитхабе такие библиотеки. Но начать можете с **Boost**. В его составе есть **MPL (Metaprogramming Library)**, в которой есть шаблон класса `quote*`, который использует *template template parameter*.
[Synopsis](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/quote.html#synopsis):

```
template<
      template< typename P1 > class F
    , typename Tag = unspecified
    >
struct quote1
{
    // unspecified
    // ...
};

...

template<
      template< typename P1,... typename Pn > class F
    , typename Tag = unspecified
    >
struct quoten
{
    // unspecified
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Так чем template template лучше в этом примере?

Comment: В том, что не дает пользователю выбрать тип для хранимых значений в контейнере

Comment: Так это же плохо :)

Comment: Если класс разработан для работы с определённым типом, то хорошо) `int` для примера. Ведь это может быть какой-то другой тип, например класс, который Вы сами разработаете

Comment: Ну вот мне интересно увидеть реальный пример ситуации, когда именно такая работа нужна. Возможно, это используется в каком-то паттерне или библиотеке. Просто ссылка на реальный код, где это используется, тоже подойдёт

Comment: У меня второй код не компилируется, ругается на контейнер без указания типа хранимых данных

Comment: Мне нужно было написать шаблонную функцию, не зависящую от контейнера и данных, но возвращающую элемент коллекции. То есть что-то вроде `template <typename TData, template <typename T> typename TCont>
TData foo(TCont<TData> arr)`, но это не работает - ругается на выбор шаблона для `foo<int, std::vector>(/*vector<int>*/ arr)`. И второй пример, как оказалось, компилироваться не хочет.

Comment: @MaxLevs C++17? Второй пример в С++17 нормально компилруется.

Comment: @EOF да, clang. `error: template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter
    Foo<int, double, std::vector> obj1;` Указывает на std::vector

Comment: @MaxLevs залетайте в чат по С++. [link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26298/c-c)

Comment: @EOF залетел, скинул скрины