# Алиас для специализации класса с параметром-шаблоном работает по-разному в gcc и clang

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, gcc, language-lawyer, clang

```
#include <iostream>

template <class>
struct B {};

template <template<class> class>
struct A {
  A() { std::cout << "1\n"; }
};

template <>
struct A<B> {
  A() { std::cout << "2\n"; }
};

template <class T>
using C = B<T>;

int main() {
  A<B>{}, A<C>{};
}
```

Почему выводы gcc и clang отличаются ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WWMbhe))? Кто прав и почему?

> gcc 10.2:
>
> > 2
> >
> > 2
>
> clang 10.0.0:
>
> > 2
> >
> > 1

Comment: Просто Clang  генерирует более оптимизированный код для архитектуры x86, отличается от gcc при упрощении кода. На этот и предыдущий ваш вопрос, я бы ответил, что прав тот, кто говорит: "Старайтесь не писать не переносимый код"

Comment: Кажется, здесь прав gcc, поскольку `std::is_same<B<int>,C<int>>::value` - истина с точки зрения обоих компиляторов.

Comment: [Passing template alias as template template parameter causes specialization matching to fail](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26093)

Comment: Я вообще вот эту конструкцию не понял `template <template<class> class>`. Что это за извращение? =)

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον шаблонный параметр, который сам является шаблоном

Comment: @dIm0n, до этого я догадался, но разве просто typename T не примет шаблонный класс?

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1161945/398802

Comment: @dIm0n, очень сложно читается и бессмысленно, особенно после появления концептов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это [core issue 1286](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286).

Насколько я понимаю, сейчас прав Clang. Если предложенные по ссылке изменения добавят в стандарт, тогда прав будет GCC.