# Параметрезированный typename в шаблоне?

Tags: c++

Возможно ли, при объявлении шаблонной функции - указать, что задаваемый typename так же будет параметризован?
Например:

```
template <typename t1, typename t2<T>>
void SomeFunc()
{
t1 var;
t2<T> list;
std::invoke(&t2::insert,list,var)
}

int main()
{
SomeFunc<std::list<std::string>,std::string>();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `template <typename x_T1, template <typename xx_T> typename x_T2>`, `SomeFunc<::std::string, ::std::list>();`

Comment: А зачем вам это?

Comment: [Зачем-нужны-template-template-параметры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1161945/398802)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется шаблонный параметр шаблона (template template parameter).

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

template <class T1, template<class> class V>
void SomeFunc()
{
    V<T1> l;
}
 
int main()
{
    SomeFunc<std::string, std::list>();
    return 0;
}
```

Если аргумент для шаблонного параметра имеет параметры по умолчанию, их придётся учитывать. Например, `std::vector` на самом деле имеет два параметра-типа.

Comment: А что значит "их придётся учитывать"? В каком смысле?