# Специализировать шаблон шаблоном

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Есть некий класс шаблонный контейнер, хочу сделать чтобы он поддерживал `std::unique_ptr` в качестве содержимого, но реализацию некоторых методов нужно изменить (сделать move вместо копирования), так вот, можно ли как-то специализировать эти методы для всех `std::unique_ptr`?

Пытался сделать так `template<class T> void Container<std::unique_ptr<T> >::linearise()` - компилятор ругается.

Не понимаю, как следующая информация относится к вопросу, но добавил по просьбе комментаторов.

Вот так работаю с теми что принимают T:

```cpp
void push_back(T const & elem) {
  if (m_size == m_capacity)
    throw std::overflow_error("Pushing to full container");
    m_body[realPlace(m_size)] = elem;
    ++m_size;
}

void push_back(T && elem) {
  if (m_size == m_capacity)
    throw std::overflow_error("Pushing to full container");
  m_body[realPlace(m_size)] = std::move(elem);
  ++m_size;
}
```

Вот пример метода который не принимает аргумментов, но требует информации о содержимом:

```cpp
 T* linearize() {
   if (is_linear())
     return m_body;
   byte *oldMemPool = m_memPool;
   T *oldBody = m_body;
   alloc_body(m_capacity);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
     m_body[i] = oldBody[realPlace(i)];
   m_begin = 0;
   delete[] oldMemPool;
   return m_body;
}
```

Comment: Речь про методы без аргументов, с теми что принимают T понятно что делать.

Comment: Показали бы в вопросе хоть один из таких функций_членов

Comment: И как вы работаете с теми, которые T принимают...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan добавил такую функцию

Comment: @Harry показал как работаю с теми которые принимают

Comment: Я не вижу тут `unique_ptr<T>`. Как я вас понял, такую специализацию для `unique_ptr<T>`, в которой функция зависит от `T`, вы написали "*Речь про методы без аргументов, с теми что принимают T понятно что делать*" - вот я и хочу понять, как именно вы справились с этой задачей - специализацией для `unique_ptr<T>` функции, зависящей от `T`.

Comment: @Harry Речь про специализацию контейнера, для того чтобы в нем были `unique_ptr` и пример функции этого контейнера которая по-разному ведет себя для копируемых значений и для unique_ptr есть в вопросе (перегруженный push_back)

Comment: *"Специализировать шаблон шаблоном"* -- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1161945/398802

Comment: @dIm0n Верно, с моей стороны не вполне корректный заголовок, я имел в виду специализацию конкретным шаблоном (unique_ptr), а не шаблоном вообще

Comment: Приведите [mre], как "компилятор ругается"

Comment: @dIm0n  в реализации соответственно мув вместо копирования.
А воспроизвести проблему полностью это неприличное количество совершенно не относящегося к проблеме кода кидать
```error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class CycleContainer::Container<std::unique_ptr<_Tp> >’                                                                                                                  template<class T> void Container<std::unique_ptr<T> >::linearise() { ```

Comment: В [mre] по определению не может быть неотносящегося к проблеме кода

Comment: Так вы хотите специализировать только одну функцию? Или весь класс?

Comment: @Harry только функцию, остальные работают с этим типом нормально и без специализации

Comment: У меня торможение _  не понял что нужно,  Интересно будет знать ответ, по сему отмечу вопрос, что он отражает стремление разобраться.

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем обрабатывать `unique_ptr` особым образом? *"реализацию некоторых методов нужно изменить (сделать move вместо копирования),"* А всегда делать move нельзя?

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что специализировать только одну **нешаблонную** функцию из шаблонного класса не получится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, прямого решения не вижу, но вот такой обходной маневр - связанный с тем, что `unique_ptr` можно перемещать, но не копировать.

Я привожу свой простой пример, думаю, для себя вы разберетесь, как применить:

```
template<typename T>
struct C {
    void doit();
};

template<typename T>
void C<T>::doit()
{
    if constexpr (!is_copy_constructible_v<T> && is_move_constructible_v<T>)
        cout << "doit<UPT>\n";
    else
        cout << "doit<T>\n";
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    C<int> a;
    C<unique_ptr<int>> b;

    a.doit();
    b.doit();
}
```

Comment: Что, никак @dIm0n не угомонится? :) Я же написал - списался со Страуструпом. Он написал примерно так - что он согласен с моим мнением (что безопаснее писать `const char*`), и что `char*` - проблема исторического свойства (*I agree, but it is hard to mess with the ancient past - you don't know who you might hurt. I \*think\* I tried this and failed almost 40 years ago*.).

Comment: Поскольку формально я получил разрешение :) делать так, если мой компилятор это позволяет (*You might simply accept both*), так что, признавая стандарт, я из принципа оставляю все как есть, пока мне не покажут хоть один компилятор, который этот `const` не примет или некорректно себя поведет (UB), при этом корректно принимая `char**`. Как только такой компилятор будет найден, вернемся к этому разговору. До тех пор оставляю все, как есть. Поскольку это работает и более безопасно, чем `char**`. Готов поспорить, что компилятора, который это не примет, вы не найдете (ну разве что напишете сами)...

Comment: В используемых вами ответах это никак не влияет на безопасность, но влияет на переносимость программ, так как implementation defined по стандарту

Comment: @dIm0n Ну... Мне просто лень лезть и перенастраивать шаблон программы в любимом редакторе. Тем более что на суть вопросов и ответов это не влияет. Дальше - как хотите, я достаточно пожил, чтоб пытаться договориться с занудой прекратить занудствовать :) Я даже вам помогу - вот, [развлекайтесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A195342+const+char+*+argv%5B%5D) :) - можете поставить почти 400 минусов...

Comment: На суть не влияет, но влияет на качество ответов. Люди могут использовать такой код в своих программах. Минусы на старые ответы ставить не буду, только на те, которые появились после моего комментария и которые лень исправлять даже после замечания