# Как правильно передать аргументы функции в CreateThread

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi

Здравствуйте меня интересует как передать аргументы функции передаваемой в `CreateThread`
Я использую `CreateThread(NULL,0,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(func),NULL,0,NULL)` я понял что мне нужно использовать `ThreadProc` но я совершенно не понимаю как с ней работать, я был бы очень благодарен если-бы привели пример

Comment: Точно нужен WinAPI? В стандартной библиотеке есть [портабельный функционал](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/thread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 параметр как раз получает указатель на нужные для потока данные. Давайте попробуем обычный int туда пробросить (код немного не для промышленного использования, а только для понимания)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI MyThread(void* p)
{
    int loop = (int)p; // вернем тип назад
    for(int i = 0; i < loop; ++i)
    {
        cout << i;
        Sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}  

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int loop = 7; // наш параметр
    CreateThread(0,4096,MyThread,(void*)loop,0,NULL);
    // скастим и передадим      ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cout << '-';
        Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Выглядит дико, но на то он и `void*`. В рабочем коде этим параметром передавайте указатель на какую-нибудь структуру, созданную динамически (если это будет указатель на структуру на стеке, тогда нужно побеспокоится, что бы поток "жил меньше, чем до выхода из вызывающего скоупа". В случае динамической структуры также нужно решить, кто и когда будет чистить память. Есть такие варианты:

- поток сам почистит (в начале своей работы или в конце)
- поток в этой структуре оставит "свои расчеты", и вызывающий поток подхватит их.
- java-стайл - операционнка за нами подчистит память.

В целом, первый вариант выглядит где то так.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

// это структура для связи
struct mydata
{
    int loop;
    string message;
};

DWORD WINAPI MyThread(void* p)
{
    mydata * d = (mydata*)p; // конвертируем указатель в правильный
    for(int i = 0; i < d->loop; ++i)
    {
        cout << d->message << " " << i;
        Sleep(1);
    }
    delete d; // чистим, когда оно нам не нужно
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    mydata * d = new mydata{7, "hello"}; // создаем экземпляр для работы
    CreateThread(0,4096,MyThread,(void*)d,0,NULL);
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cout << '-';
        Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

конечно, этому коду нужно подобавлять всякие проверки на то, что поток создался и подобное, но в целом - это уже рабочий код.

Comment: здравствуйте ваш ответ мне показался более удобным, но я похоже что-то не понял почему если убрать цикл `for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)` то ничего не выводится на экран?

Comment: Вы о цикле в главном потоке? а в этом случае main завершается очень быстро. Явно раньше потока. А по выходу с main рантайм позовет ExitProcess, который завершит все потоки. К этому моменту дочерний поток мог даже не успеть запуститься либо запустился, но его данные ещё никуда не распечатались (они буфере). Вот и получается

Answer (score 2):

Ну, [вот пример](https://rextester.com/GAGN9766), как его вызвать (упрощенный, без проверок). Тут же второй пример, как это же сделать, не заморачиваясь работой с API, а только средствами C++.

```
DWORD WINAPI Thread1(void*)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cout << i;
        Sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}

void Thread2()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cout << char('A'+i);
        Sleep(10);
    }
}

int main([[maybe_unused]] int argc,
         [[maybe_unused]] const char * argv[])
{
    CreateThread(0,4096,Thread1,0,0,NULL);
    thread th(Thread2);
    th.detach();
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cout << '-';
        Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Можете пользоваться тем, что больше по душе :)

Comment: прикольно. теперь кроме `const` появился ещё и `[[maybe_unused]]`. Я долго не понимал, зачем так писать - это наивно и бессмысленно. Но потом понял. фишка то в другом, константность просто для отвода глаз...

Comment: @KoVadim В комментариях к https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1177629/195342 я уже (в который раз) описал свою позицию :) Если уж сам Страуструп не против, то кто я такой, чтоб с ним спорить? :) P.S. И еще - я ненавижу, когда на меня давят, особенно когда давят глупо :) Нравится кому-то пальцы растопыривать и минусы ставить? Да без проблем...

Comment: и где же давят, где же минусы ставят?

Comment: @KoVadim ну так только к этому ответу уже двое. Одного альтернативного :) я знаю, интересно, кто второй? :) Или кое-кто завел себе второй аккаунт? :) Заметим в скобках, что минусы ставят за верный по сути ответ, т.е. правильность ответа этих людей совсем не интересует, это просто "такую личную неприязнь испитываю - просто кушать не могу!" :) Ну что ж, караван идет дальше... :)

Comment: о, анонимный минусатор стал известен? а то я тоже хочу его посмотреть. вот в соседнем ответе переплюнули по const

Comment: @KoVadim Так dIm0n и не скрывается, что он мне за каждый const минус лепит...

Comment: тогда у user7860670 уже должно быть три. Значит не за const.

Comment: @KoVadim За `const` минусы - это только мне, другие не доросли еще :) Тут, как я уже писал,  [*такую личную неприязнь испытываю - просто кушать не могу!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNfrmqotQYU)

Answer (score 0):

Вот более-менее полноценный пример:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstddef>

struct
t_ThreadContext
{
    char const * psz_message;
    ::std::exception_ptr p_exception;
};

DWORD WINAPI
thread_proc(LPVOID const param) noexcept
{
    assert(param);
    DWORD exit_code{ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION};
    auto & context{*static_cast<t_ThreadContext *>(param)};
    assert(context.psz_message);
    try
    {
        // do some work...
        ::std::cout << context.psz_message << ::std::endl;
        exit_code = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // intersept exception so it can be inspected in parent thread
        context.p_exception = ::std::current_exception();
        exit_code = ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
    }
    if (STILL_ACTIVE == exit_code)
    {
        exit_code = ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
    }
    return exit_code;
}

int
main([[maybe_unused]] int const argc, [[maybe_unused]] char const * const * const pp_args)
{
    int exit_code{EXIT_FAILURE};
    try
    {
        auto const & psz_command{pp_args[0]};
        ::t_ThreadContext context{psz_command};
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES p_security_attributes{}; // nullptr - default security
        DWORD stack_size{}; // 0 - default
        DWORD flags{}; // 0 - default (create thread and run it immediately)
        DWORD thread_id{};
        auto const h_thread
        {
            ::CreateThread
            (
                p_security_attributes
            ,   stack_size
            ,   ::std::addressof(::thread_proc)
            ,   static_cast<LPVOID>(::std::addressof(context))
            ,   flags
            ,   ::std::addressof(thread_id) // may be nullptr
            )
        };
        if (not h_thread)
        {
            auto const last_error{::GetLastError()};
            // deal with error...
        }
        else
        {
            auto const wait_result{::WaitForSingleObject(h_thread, INFINITE)};
            if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != wait_result)
            {
                auto const last_error{::GetLastError()};
                // error here is most likely fatal...
            }
            else
            {
                if (not ::CloseHandle(h_thread))
                {
                    auto const last_error{::GetLastError()};
                    // error here is most likely fatal...
                }
                else
                {
                    // inspect exception occurred in child thread
                    if (context.p_exception)
                    {
                        ::std::rethrow_exception(context.p_exception);
                    }
                    exit_code = EXIT_SUCCESS;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        exit_code = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return exit_code;
}
```

Пояснения:

1. Пользовательские данные можно передавать посредством непрозрачного указателя `void *`, который передается четвертым аргументом в `CreateThread`, а затем пробрасывается в процедуру потока.
2. Процедура потока, как разные другие С функции обратного вызова из WinAPI, обязана не допускать проброса С++ исключений через границы языка. Поэтому ее имеет смысл объявлять как `noexcept`, а возникающие исключения перехватывать и либо сразу обрабатывать, либо передавать для обработки в главный поток посредством `::std::exception_ptr`.
3. Значение, возвращаемое процедурой потока, может быть произвольным, однако имеет смысл использовать коды ошибок Windows. Единственно исключение - в качестве кода возврата не должно использоваться значение `STILL_ACTIVE`.
4. Типичной ошибкой является игнорирование значений, возвращаемых функциями WinAPI.
5. Типичной ошибкой является игнорирование ожидания завершения потока.
6. Типичной ошибкой является игнорирование необходимости закрывать дескриптор потока.
7. По сравнению с библиотечным классом `::std::thread`, создание потоков посредством WinAPI может быть оправдано, когда требуется задавать нужный размер стека или задавать атрибуты безопасности.

Comment: с одним const  я знаю почему пишут. Но с тремя??? `char const * const * const pp_args` - поделитесь секретными наработками пожалуйста.

Comment: @KoVadim А что тут такого? Квалификатор на переменную + по одному квалификатору на каждый уровень перенаправления.

Comment: мне интересно, где Вы такое взяли.

Comment: @KoVadim Обычное соблюдение const correctness, не более того. В примере же нет необходимости изменять ни сам pp_args, ни объекты, на который тот указывает.

Comment: это какое то странное объяснение.

Comment: @KoVadim что странного-то? если написать только один const с левой стороны, то толку от него будет мало, так как и `pp_args` и `*pp_args` будут по-прежнему изменяемыми.

Comment: наличие это const нарушает стандарт. А если человек сознательно нарушает стандарт - это странно. А то о том, что значит const в разных позициях - я знаю.

Comment: @KoVadim *"наличие это const нарушает стандарт"* - что что нарушает?

Comment: Поддержка такого второго параметра зависит от реализации, самый верхний `const` можно оставить, но 2 внутренних для переносимости надо убрать. [another implementation-defined form, with int as return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)